# Open Button Link In Webview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

i am very new to Xcode and don't know much about it , sorry for my silly question.

i want to create app with 20 buttons on home page , and i want to attach them all in one ViewController

```
Like if button1 clicked
do this
elseif button2 clicked
do diffrent
```

i have added 2 buttons with google and yahoo.com 
but when i click it down it opens in same ViewController i Want To open it in Feed (ViewController2)

This is screenshot of my app
[Lovebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDTAK.png)

LoveBook attached to ViewController1 and feed attached to viewcontroller2

and this is my code in ViewController1

```
 @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string:"http://google.com")



    let request = URLRequest (url: url!)
    webView.frame = self.view.frame;

    webView.loadRequest(request)

}

@IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
     let url = URL(string:"http://yahoo.com")



    let request = URLRequest (url: url!)
    webView.frame = self.view.frame;

    webView.loadRequest(request)

}
```

please help me or send me the project demo. please thanks

Comment: Having 20 buttons with the same IBAction method but different URLS is a "code smell". Any time you have lots of duplicate code like that it's an indication that you should think about a better way to do it. In this case you could create a subclass of UIButton that has an @IBInspectable property for a URL string, and have all the buttons point to the same IBAction. Then you could set the URLs in your storyboard.

Comment: Or use tag. :D..

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote asks an external app to handle the URL.

If you want to open a web view then you'll need to create a new view controller that contains a web view, pass the URL to that view controller, and have the view controller send the link to the web view in it's `viewWillAppear` method.

(No, I don't have sample code I can share.)

Comment: how can i pass the url ? to New ViewController ?

Comment: Set up your target view controller (the one that hosts the web view) to have a `targetURL` property. In the IBAction code, instantiate the view controller and set it's `targetURL` to the desired URL before pushing/presenting the new view controller.

Comment: i already have webview in viewcontroller but when i click on button it opens on the same ViewController which is hosting the buttons